# Where to check free of charge the impact factors of all journals

Tags: publications, journals, bibliometrics

Where can one check free of charge the impact factors of all journals? jcr.clarivate.com seems to be one but it's not open to those with no subscription. Many other sources only show other metrics but not impact factors.

Comment: Is it at all clear that there is such a place where you can check for free? Clarivate is putting a substantial effort into their product, they may simply not be interested to have it available for free.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but just wonder if there's anything free out there to make things easier

Comment: Are you looking for journals for your future publications? Many journals publish their impact factor on their website. Isn't that enough?

Comment: yes and no, some new journals don't show impact factors yet some others that aren't SCI index don't have them either